# Apply conditional switches to docker build command depending on presence of environment variable

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to cleanup some of our CI/CD code around building Docker images. Given this, it would be very useful to be able to apply some switches to the `docker build` command conditionally based on the presence of environment variables. What I've come up with is:

```
docker build \
  --cache-from ${INPUT_IMAGE}:latest \
  --tag ${INPUT_IMAGE}:${INPUT_IMAGE_TAG} \
  --tag ${INPUT_IMAGE}:latest \
  "${INPUT_TARGET:+'--target' \"\$INPUT_TARGET\"}" \
  ${INPUT_CONTEXT}
```

As you can see on line 5, I want to conditionally apply the `target` switch if the `INPUT_TARGET` environment variable is present. However, each time I build Docker complains that `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.` which I suspect is an indication that the switches are getting mangled in the way they're being applied.

How can I conditionally apply the `--target` switch to the command based on the presence of the  `INPUT_TARGET` environment variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not quote the expression. In quotes, it won't be subject to word splitting and therefore presented to docker as one argument `--target VALUE` instead of `--target` and `VALUE`:

```
docker build \
  --cache-from "${INPUT_IMAGE}:latest" \
  --tag "${INPUT_IMAGE}:${INPUT_IMAGE_TAG}" \
  --tag "${INPUT_IMAGE}:latest" \
  ${INPUT_TARGET:+--target ${INPUT_TARGET}} \
  "${INPUT_CONTEXT}"
```

PS: While you quoted in the wrong place, you missed quotes in all other places :) I've added them.